# Change default behavior of a check box

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, file-association

When I double click a file that doesn't have a program associated with it, I get the **How do you want to open this file?** dialog box where I can chose a program, the problem is *Always use this app to open .ext file* is checked by default, many tutorials like [this one](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/156072-how-add-remove-open-always-use-app-windows-10-a.html) provide a way to remove it, I **do not** want that, I just want the check box to be unchecked.

The question has been already [asked at Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/always-use-this-app-to-open-files-checkbox-on/07308ebc-d719-4a39-b0fd-0dc9a9477ccc) but they are refusing to provide help. Any way to do it through registry?

Comment: They actually have answered your question.  They indicated you should provide feedback to Microsoft so the future necessary change might be made.  You will just have to accept, this particular feature of Windows works for the time being

Comment: Also they were pretty vague about not messing with the registry using *If there is a possible registry key that needs to be modified in order to have it, we don't recommend to do it* (understandable) and the question is somewhat old.

Comment: It might be old but it’s accurate.  Windows doesn’t change that often

Comment: Maybe someone discovered a hack in the meantime.